# Android studio java coordinate marker

Tags: java, android, maps

how can I make it so that when I click on a button, I can select a specific point on Google Maps, the coordinates of which will be stored in the textview field near the button, and after clicking on the text of these coordinates, the map will open with the previously selected marker displayed?

Code im using to including Google maps in my application:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
```

This code im using to open map :

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap gMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gMap = googleMap;
        gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude+ " : " + latLng.longitude);
                gMap.clear();
                gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
                gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here are the dependencies I added to my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="REDACTED"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating new marker at your every attempt, so you see the previous one. I think your implementation would be like below.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap gMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gMap = googleMap;
     MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions(); --> Marker options should be here 
        gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude+ " : " + latLng.longitude);
                gMap.clear();
                gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
                gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        });
    }
}
```